# Store a key that will persist after App is unInstalled

Tags: android, system, keystore, secret-key

I need to store a key on the device in a secure way that will persist after the installing application is un-installed. Heres what I want to happen:

- User installs app for the first time, the app creates and stores a secret key without prompting the user
- User closes the app
- user reopens the app, app grabs key
- user un-installs the app and deletes all application related data stored on the device
- user re-installs the same app
- user opens newly installed app, app grabs the secret key without having to recreate or prompt user

Is this possible without creating a file in external storage? I dont want to use the KeyChain API as its only supported >API14 and requires user prompting

Comment: Connecting to a server side db maybe?

Comment: The idea is that my server should be able to recognize the device by passing this key through an API call upon app-initialization

Comment: Use the unique android device id

Comment: There seem to be a lot of documented problems with using the ANDROID_ID. plus, I need to be able to change the key after it is created

Comment: Gotcha and fair enough :)

Comment: Basically, trying to prevent the user from being able to reset this is going to be an exercise in frustration.  So don't bother - rework your business requirement so that this is not a major concern.  There's nothing other than the external storage which should survive re-install, and anything on the external storage is subject to manual removal.  The unique ID solutions may work sometimes when tracked off device (and you could re-runnably derive something from them) but there are many specific-model issues with that.

Comment: I was randomly thinking about this this morning. What if you saved the key on the user's phone in a database or a file as an encrypted key? Then on reinstall just pull it from the preexisting database and decrypt it, if you even want encryption security